# Teacher supplied library for x86_64 incompatible with my system

Tags: c, gcc, 32bit-64bit, x86-64, 32-bit

I have been given an assignment in school, and my lecture has stated that we need to use his pre compiled C library which contains an important function definition.

I have tried removing all current *.o files from the dir, there isn't any there currently.

The problem i have currently is as follows:

```
   i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `libnavigation.a(great_circle.o)' is    incompatible     with i386 output
```

where libnavigation.a is the library name which contains the great_circle function.

uname -ma

```
Linux chris-SATELLITE-PRO-C850 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:19:42 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I have tried adding the several command options to gcc

1. -m32 results in the same error error:
2. -m64 results in the error:

   ```
    gcc     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/c_assignment build/Debug/GNU-Linux-  
    x86/line_counter.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-  
    x86/mayday.o  

    build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/rescue_assets.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/ship.o 

   build/Debug/GNU-

   Linux-x86/system_handler.o libnavigation.a -lm -m64
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc.a when 

   searching for -lgcc
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc_s.so when   

   searching for -lgcc_s
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc.a when        

   searching for -lgcc
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc_s.so when 

   searching for -lgcc_s
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
   ```

i am not sure how to progress from here, i've asked the teacher but no response as of yet.

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: If you are working on a 32 bit system and you are supplied with a  64 bit library there's not much you can do.

Comment: the lib provided was made using x86_64 linux. which i thought was 64it linux for 32bit systems?

Comment: Explain the problem to your lecturer and ask for a 32 bit version.

Comment: x86_64 is for 64 bit systems, A general rule of thumb in your classes is to always assume you work in 64 bits. Unless specified otherwise, or if you work on embedded systems

Comment: @chris: it wouldn't make sense to build a 64 bit OS for 32 bit machines. x86_64 is one of the names used for the 64 bit architecture currently used in most "normal" computers (it's called like that since it's a 64 bit extension of the older x86 family).

Comment: ah, i understand i thought that might have been the case, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to go from here

1. Ask the teacher to compile a 32-bit library
2. Use 64-bit linux

64-bit libraries are for 64-bit computers, 32-bit libraries are for 32-bit computers.
That's why software writers go through some additional effort to make 64-bit software, since 64-bit hardware has come into common use.

Comment: bit of a pain, i thought they would have compiled it for 32 bit since the school computers run 32bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a Toshiba SATELLITE PRO C850. All of the laptops of this family are fitted with a 64 bit CPU.

I would recommend to reinstall your OS selecting the 64 bit version. Note that a 64 bit OS can run 32 bit code.

If you don't want or aren't allowed to reinstall and your CPU is an Intel i3 or i5. You still have the possibility to install VirtualBox and create a 64 bit VM in it where you'll be able to use the 64 bit library.